# How to connect fire to Lord Business' Coffee Mugs?

Tags: building, connections, the-lego-movie

So, we have [Lord Business' Evil Lair (70809-1)](https://brickset.com/sets/70809-1/Lord-Business-Evil-Lair), and we also have some two-tone flames from [another set](https://brickset.com/sets/70821-1/Emmet-and-Benny-s-Build-and-Fix-Workshop!).

How can the flames be attached to Lord Biz' coffee mugs (as seen in The LEGO Movie)?

[image]

---

[image] + [image]

The flame shaft can be connected to plenty of parts, such as a "Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud".

However...the mug part has an unusual inner diameter that studs don't fit into. So I'm wondering how this was constructed for the film - or if the animators didn't actually make a construction but just placed the flames for the shot, is there *some* way they can be connected to at least approximate the way they appear in the film?

(I mean, without having to resort to... the Kragle!)

Comment: Stop messing with my stuff!

Answer (score 12):

They might have cheated in the movie, but an old 8 toothed gear fits snugly in the hole.

[image: Picture]

[image: 8 toothed gear]